# How to interact with a (variable name unknown) javascript object in a dynamically loaded file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, queue.js

Mike Bostock's [queue.js](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) library currently allows me to load a variable number and type of files (css, json, js etc) into a nascent single page browser application:

```
d3.json("files_to_load.json", function(data) {

  var q = queue(1);

  data.forEach(function(d, i) {
    q.defer(load_file, d.filename, d.filetype);
  });

  q.awaitAll(function(error, results) {
    console.log("results.toSource()=" + results.toSource());
  });

});
```

..where:

- `load_file()` simply builds a script specification for appending to the DOM, much the same as the `load_image()` function shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081023/queue-js-to-preload-images-is-waiting-forever-callbak/18086989#18086989).
- the queue.awaitAll() results (here for a successful but extreme case comprising nine files) show an array of seemingly useless `(void 0)`, ie `undefined` objects:

  `results.toSource()=[(void 0), (void 0), (void 0), (void 0), (void 0), (void 0), (void 0), (void 0), (void 0)]`

Somewhere amongst these will always one representing the loading of a js file containing a simple closure, the variable name of which is both **unknown** and **differs**, but whose **interface is standard** across all js files:

```
var closure_with_var_name_unknown = function() {
  var id = "";
  var privateFunction = function() {
      // use id in a way specific to this file
  }
  return {
    callPrivateFunc : function() {
       privateFunction();
    },
    customise : function(what, val) {
       id = val; // in a switch (what) case statement
    }
  }
}();
```

So, having loaded this js file into the DOM, and assuming customise() is a common to all such js files and closures, I would like to **get a handle on the current closure variable** in order to call customise, as in:

```
closure_with_var_name_unknown.customise("id", d.id);
```

Would be nice if this were to occur within the q.awaitAll() callback function's success block. :-)

Strategy suggestions? (No jQuery, please).

Thanks!

Comment: the best strategy is to have a map of `file name -> closure name`, so depending on file loaded, call the appropriate closure. Else one would have to parse the code as string and extract the closure name (if exists)

Comment: Can I in fact store a variable in json? Promising as the approach sounds, and the variable returned from a map looking plausible `[object Object]`, it seems to know nothing of it's own `customise()` function. Hence, now looking at the possibility of transfer using  `d3.dispatch()`